# UICollectionView rounded imageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UIImageView inside a UICollectionView Cell.

I wanted there to be 2 cells per column in the uicollectionview so I used this code....

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let padding: CGFloat = 25
    let collectionCellSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

  return CGSize(width: collectionCellSize/2, height: collectionCellSize/2)

}
```

For the image view I wanted it to be round, and this code usually works elsewhere..

```
self.accountImageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
self.accountImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

I have tried putting that in the cellForItemAt, with no luck

Now inside the CollectionView Cell Class I added it like this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()

    self.accountImageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
    self.accountImageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

The image looks like a deflated football.

Is the padding code messing up the rounded image view code?

Comment: Did you set constraints for your UIImageView on IB?

Comment: Yes it is a 1:1 ratio and 15 from top and 15 from bottom and horizontally centered

Comment: are you sure your imageview is a square one?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `self.accountImageView.layoutIfNeeded()`.
And make sure height and width of your ***imageview*** is equal

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.accountImageView.layoutIfNeeded()       // add this
    self.accountImageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
    self.accountImageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraint then try this -

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
 super.layoutSubviews()
 self.accountImageView.layoutIfNeeded() // Add this line

 self.accountImageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2
 self.accountImageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: And Make sure your image view is a square, means height = width

Comment: Ok, so I wanted to test it, and I took off all the circular code, and just ran it normal. The image is a rectangle EVEN with my constraints saying width 50 height 50....